# Returning new unmutated state with Object.assign & lodashs _.merge function?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, lodash, mutation

Just came across something I don't understand. It's about redux state + lodashs _.merge function.

**This does not work:**

```
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
  const merge = {
    active: {
      userId: nextUserId
    }
  };

  return _.merge(newState, merge);
```

**Whereas this does work:**

```
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
  const merge = {
    active: {
      userId: nextUserId
    }
  };

  return _.merge({}, newState, merge);
```

The difference is the last line:

```
  return _.merge(newState, merge);
```

vs. :

```
  return _.merge({}, newState, merge);
```

I don't seem to understand why this makes a difference here though? `_.merge` is mutative, so it's best to "mutate" a newly created object, and not state itself - **but** in the first case, I am creating a new Object with `Object.assign` and return this as the new state. I am never once mutating state. Or am I? What is the problem here?

Comment: upppps reading over this i feel like it might have something to do with having made `newState` a `const` ...

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with newState being a const. Declaring something as a const doesn't have any effect on the way an object behaves aside from the fact that if you try to reassign it an error is thrown.

also btw, you can still mutate consts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` creates a shallow copy, so any property deeper than level 1 still reference to the original state,

> This does not work: ?

```
 return _.merge(newState, merge);
```

The `newState` is the destination object where the properties from `merge` object will be copied recursively, and since `newState` still refers to original state so any mutation eventually mutates original state

> Whereas this does work:

```
  return _.merge({}, newState, merge);
```

The `{}` is the destination object where the properties from `newState` and `merge` object will be copied recursively, and since `{}` does not refers to original state so any mutation eventually will not effect original state